# Arrangement on a regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics

If $N$ people are to be arranged around a $K$ sided regular polygon such that each side of that polygon will have equal number of people, then what would be the number of arrangements?

Comment: You should provide some more context details if you don't want your post to be deleted.

Comment: Knights of the Polygonal Table? Nice variant.

Comment: Do people get assigned only to an edge?  Do people get assigned to vertices and count towards both edges?  Does the order of people along an edge matter??  So many clarifications, so little time...

Answer (score 0):

And the general solution for this problem such that N people are to be arranged around a K sided regular polygon such that each side of that polygon will have equal number of people,say M, such that N = MK then the number of arrangements is
$$ \frac{N!}{K.(M!)^K}$$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: The $K!$ in the denominator should just be $K$ as it accounts for rotations of the polygon.  It would be $K!$ if you were just dividing the $N$ people into $K$ groups, but presumably we care about the order of the groups around the polygon here.

Comment: Sure sir,  treat it as if it is a circle and no of people.  Good catch after a long time.